# How to fix SQL error with dropping a table in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mariadb

I have created a web you can upload and download files - everything works perfect. But now, I want to create a init file, that delete old records in database and create a new tables in it.

So I write this:

```
$command = "
IF OBJECT_ID(`".$database.".Users`) IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE ".$database.".Users; 
IF OBJECT_ID(`".$database.".Uploads`) IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE ".$database.".Uploads; 

CREATE TABLE `Users` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `User` text NOT NULL,
  `Password` text NOT NULL,
  `Permission` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=0 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `Users` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`Id`);
ALTER TABLE `Users` MODIFY `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=0;

CREATE TABLE `Uploads` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Name` text NOT NULL,
  `User` text NOT NULL,
  `Comment` text NOT NULL,
  `Path` text NOT NULL,
  `Permission` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Date` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=0 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `Uploads` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`Id`);
ALTER TABLE `Uploads` MODIFY `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=0;
";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $command) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
```

I think, that code is right (but obviously not). When I run it, SQL throws an error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF OBJECT_ID(`db.Users`) IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE db.User' at line 1**.

This means that it don’t have a problem with connection to SQL database.

I tried instead of `IF OBJECT_ID` use `IF NOT EXISTS`, but it doesn't works too. Can anybody tell me if multi-line SQL command is this problem or if it is  something else?

Note: I use 5.5.37 version of MariaDB (if it helps)

Comment: There are many places where you used single quotes `'` instead of ticks `\``.

Comment: Yeah, but I tried it even with ticks, but result was same.

Comment: Still; you're going to have to update your question contain the real syntax for all this. It could be closed based on that also.

Comment: You need to delimit table and field names with ` instead of '; and they must be delimited separately...maybe, I've never seen OBJECT_ID used in Mysql/MariaDB, only MSSQL. Also, unless MariaDB has drastically diverged from MySQL, you cannot execute scripts as queries. You need to execute those one at a time, and use `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS` since you cannot use `IF`.

Comment: Sorry - Now it is right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IF` is not a valid SQL statement in MySQL / MariaDB.

The `IF OBJECT_ID(...)` statement in the question appears to be a Transact-SQL (Microsoft SQL Server) construct.

The equivalent functionality in MySQL would be achieved with

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS foo.mytable ;
```

(I expect this would work in MariaDB 5.5, but I haven't verified.)

Note that if the table doesn't exist, the execution of the statement will raise a warning. (A warning message, not an error message.)

---

The **`mysqli_query`** function runs a single statement. To run multiple statements, we can use **`mysqli_multi_query`** function, documented here:

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php

Comment: mysqli_multi_query - That it is! Thanks!

Comment: Avoid `mysqli_multi_query` for security reasons.  Either issue multiple commands from PHP (not a problem), or write a Stored Procedure to encapsulate it all together, then `CALL` the SP.

Answer (score 1):

As far as concerns, OBJECT_ID does not exist in mysql, only in mssql. [Searching for OBJECT_ID mysql 8.0 reference manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/search/?d=201&p=1&q=Object_id) does not retun anything meaningful. Even if it existed, your syntax for IF block does not look good : you want `IF...THEN...END`.

To fix the error, you can replace this :

```
IF OBJECT_ID(`".$database.".Users`) IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE ".$database.".Users; 
IF OBJECT_ID(`".$database.".Uploads`) IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE ".$database.".Uploads;
```

With :

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ".$database.".Users;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ".$database.".Uploads;
```

Comment: I wrote, that I tried it, but not works. (Now, I tried it again, but it doesn't works again)

Comment: @GBM After change "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS db.Uploads; CREATE TABLE `Users` ( `Id`' at line 2" (Nearly same)

Answer (score 0):

never used  OBJECT_ID but what you want seem to be easily doable with 
"drop table if exists users;"

Comment: oh sorry i misunderstood.  you wrote - "I tried instead of IF OBJECT_ID use IF NOT EXISTS"  i thought you tried writing 'IF not EXIST' in create table query not in drop table query